# Official page of Weka for SVM java code

Tags: classification, svm, weka

I am using Weka to train a model from few days. I know Weka use Java code to implement a classifier. I also heard that Weka has some github pages to describe the java code for the classifiers. I like to know the SVM java code which is used in WEKA. I found few webpages describing Java code for SVM classifiers for WEKA. I can not understand which one is there official page.

Providing me the link to SVM GitHub page would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official Weka source code is [stored in a local Gitlab git repository](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/git/) (not on Github).

Note that there are two versions of SVM commonly used with Weka:

- The [SMO](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html) classifier, [source code here](https://git.cms.waikato.ac.nz/weka/weka/-/blob/main/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.java).
- The [LibSVM wrapper](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/lib_svm/): an external library  that can be used in Weka (i.e. the source code is not part of Weka).

Comment: I am looking for the code to understand how categorical data is handled in SVM. Because I found if I feed the SVM classifier with categorical data classifier did not throw the error, which is common for sklearn. So I want to know what part of the java code categorical data has been handled.

Comment: @Encipher in Weka categorical features must be declared as `nominal` in the `arff` file, this is how it's handled (not specific to SVM). I assume that any feature declared as `nominal` is one-hot-encoded, but I never actually checked the code.

Comment: Yeah I searched and found they have an unsupervised filter `nominaltobanry` which is based on one hot encoding and they just import that file on SVM.